# ASUS UX360CA Input problems

Tags: 16.04, gnome, touchpad, ubuntu-gnome, touchscreen

I installed Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 on my ASUS UX360CAK tablet and it works fine. However, I've come across some problems with input. The touchpad settings are VERY minimal and I can only get it to register clicks when I physically "click" the touchpad. No settings for scroll direction, multitouch gestures etc. Sometimes the cursor will dissappear and appear randomly, for those occasions, I use the touchscreen. Recently, GNOME crashed (completely frozen, happened when closing a tab with middle mouse click) and restarted, throwing out an "Ubuntu 16.04 has run across an error." or something, I can't access the crash log (no perms). I did see something like xorg crashed with sigsegv in miPointerSetPosition(). Any ideas as to what might be going on here? I wonder if it has to do with display or input drivers.

Comment: It's side effect of trying Asus to be Apple. It is very likely that the touchpad is proprietary, as in UX310. Try to report bug about touchpad to Asus or at least to [bugs.launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net). As temporary solution you can disable the touchpad and use external mouse.

Comment: @N0rbert which is what I've been doing. It's not too too bad, but still annoying. Any idea about the crash? Hasn't happened since.

Comment: No ideas, just pity. You may add some output to your question - `xinput | grep Touch`, `cat /var/log/dmesg | grep -i touch`, `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep -i touch`. On UX310 touchpad freezes all system after some normal actions with touchpad (tested with all kernels and Ubuntu releases).

Comment: The first command output `⎜   ↳ ELAN1200:00 04F3:3045 Touchpad           id=12 [slave  pointer  (2)]`, second one does nothing, third one says no file or directory.